# Why to_json returned a String not equal with the same json String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

In Rails console

```
> h_json = {key: "value"}.to_json;
#=> "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
> s_json = %Q|{"key": "value"}|
#=> "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
> s_json.class
#=> String
> h_json.class
#=> String
```

We can see both `h_json` and `s_json` have the same String class, and looks the same, however

```
#=> "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
> s_json == h_json
#=> false
```

They don't equals each other, I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you certain that you've pasted the correct version of `h_json`? `#to_json` would generally produce `{"key":"value"}` (i.e. no space after the colon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a space in the `s_json`, if you checked the source code of the to_json function

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoders/hash.rb, line 33
def to_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
  hash = as_json(options)

  result = '{'
  result << hash.map do |key, value|
    "#{ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(key.to_s)}:#{ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(value, options)}"
  end * ','
  result << '}'
end
```

this function doesn't add a space between the colon `:` and the value.

So actually, 
`h_json = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"`

and

`s_json = "{\"key\": \"value\"}"`

if you set `s_json = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"` they must be equal.